# Importing to Google Sheets firts/second/third occurrence of class on website

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import to a Google Sheet separated numbers of followers, post and ER for Instagram accounts using data from this site: https://igstats.net/report/jenniferanistononline/instagram (this account only for an example).

Piece of code that includes those data:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center mt-4 mt-lg-0 pl-sm-0">
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        Followers <p class="report-header-number">4,319</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        Uploads <p class="report-header-number">93</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        Engagement <p class="report-header-number">3.78%</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to receive xpaths to formulas that will give me separated results for all metrics.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formulas work for me (as of October 22nd 2019):

- Followers

  ```
  =IMPORTXML("https://igstats.net/report/jenniferanistononline/instagram", "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/p")
  ```
- Uploads

  ```
  =IMPORTXML("https://igstats.net/report/jenniferanistononline/instagram", "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/p")
  ```
- EM

  ```
  =IMPORTXML("https://igstats.net/report/jenniferanistononline/instagram", "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/p")
  ```

Comment: Thank you @carlesgg97. After replacing ", " with ";" it works perfectly.